expo-build-properties doesn't apply changes
I have a project running on expo 51. I have this config in my app.config.ts:
export default ({ config }: { config: ExpoConfig }): ExpoConfig => {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    [
      "expo-build-properties",
      {
        android: {
          minSdkVersion: 24,
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
}

When I run npx expo prebuild --clean and checking build.gradle, I still see this remaining unchanged:
minSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.minSdkVersion') ?: '23')

Am I doing something wrong here?
